# Reusing functions in C++

Tags: c++, virtual

I am having trouble writing a code in which a class that inherits from another class reuses a function of this class in one of its functions

file pessoa.h:

```
#ifndef PESSOA_H
#define PESSOA_H
#include "data.h"
#include <string>

class Pessoa
{
   string nome;
   Data aniversario;
public:
   Pessoa(string tnome, Data taniversario){nome = tnome; aniversario =       taniversario;}
Pessoa(){};
int Aniversario(Data data_atual); 
virtual void imprime();
~Pessoa();

};

#endif
```

file universitario.h:

```
#ifndef UNI_H
#define UNI_H
#include "pessoa.h"
#include "data.h"

class Universitario: public Pessoa
{
    int matricula;
    Data ingresso;

 public:
    Universitario(int tmatricula, Data tingresso, string nome, Data     aniversario): 
    Pessoa(nome, aniversario) {matricula = tmatricula; ingresso = tingresso;}
    Universitario(){};
    void imprime();
    ~Universitario();


};

#endif
```

function imprime() definition from pessoa.cpp:

```
void Pessoa::imprime()
{    
    cout << "Nome: " << this->nome << endl;

}
```

function imprime() definition from uni.cpp:

```
void Universitario::imprime()
{
    this->imprime();
    cout << "Matricula: " << this->matricula << endl;
    ingresso.imprimed();

}
```

The error I get is this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Pessoa::~Pessoa()", referenced from:
      Universitario::~Universitario() in main-0c1624.o
      Universitario::Universitario(int, Data,     std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,     std::__1::allocator<char> >, Data) in main-0c1624.o
  "typeinfo for Pessoa", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Universitario in main-0c1624.o
  "vtable for Pessoa", referenced from:
      Pessoa::Pessoa(std::__1::basic_string<char,    std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, Data) in main-   0c1624.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am guessing the error is either on **virtual** or **this**.

Comment: `void Universitario::imprime()
{
    this->imprime();` is an infinite loop. Change `this->imprime` into `Pessoa::imprime` if all you want is first calling the base class method.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Pessoa::~Pessoa()", referenced from:
```

You need to actually implement your destructor.  You only declared it.

Instead of this:

```
~Pessoa();
```

Try this:

```
~Pessoa() {}
```

Same holds true for the Universitario destructor.

Comment: I did that and got this: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for Pessoa", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Universitario in main-0275b3.o
  "vtable for Pessoa", referenced from:
      Pessoa::~Pessoa() in main-0275b3.o
      Pessoa::Pessoa(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, Data) in main-0275b3.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocatio

Comment: @emic: are you sure you recompiled all your .cpp files, and specified the .os when linking?  You should edit your compile steps in at the end of the question.

Comment: The destructor should probably be virtual and could be defaulted.

Comment: I forgot to include one of the files in the main file. Problem solved.